# AngularJs ng-repeat ng-init ng-show conditional break one table row

Tags: json, angularjs

Inside a ng-repeat how can i detect if one JSON value change?

If the region change i will show a row into a table with the sum of the previous column values.

Ng-init receives region values but stays always with the same value of the current region created empty on controller so i can not compare.

```
ng-init="previousRegion = uniqueitem.Region"

ng-show="{{ uniqueitem.Region !== previousRegion }}"
```

I do have a JSON with region, month value and yearly value, in this format :

```
[
    {
        "Region": "NORTH",
        "VlM": "654321",    
        "VlY": "123456"
    },
    {
        "Region": "NORTH",
        "VlM": "234567",    
        "VlY": "432765"
    },
    {
        "Region": "SOUTH",
        "VlM": "567234",    
        "VlY": "321456"
    },
    {
        "Region": "CENTER",
        "VlM": "456123",    
        "VlY": "987654"
    }
]
```

My ng-repeat :

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in data track by item.Region">
        <tr ng-repeat="uniqueitem in item" >
            <td ng-init="previousRegion = uniqueitem.Region">
              {{uniqueitem.Region}} - {{previousregion}} - 
            </td>
            <td>
              {{uniqueitem.VlM}} 
            </td>
            <td>
              {{uniqueitem.VlY}} 
            </td>
             <td 
                ng-show="{{ uniqueitem.Region !== previousRegion }}"
                ng-init="previousRegion = uniqueitem.Region">
                <b>Total</b> here will came totals
             </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of a simple listing

```
Region  M           Y 
NORTH   654321  123456
NORTH   234567  432765
SOUTH   567234  321456
CENTER  456123  987654
```

I will build a list breaking one line per region, summing the colum totals.

In the controller i do create the scope variables:

```
$scope.previousRegion ='';
$scope.sumM ='';
$scope.sumY ='';
$scope.sumMRegion ='';
$scope.sumYRegion ='';
$scope.sumMRegionTotals ='';
$scope.sumYRegionTotals ='';
```

Want to find the breaking condition to start the sum.

```
Region  M           Y 
NORTH   654321  123456
NORTH   234567  432765
>>total 888888  556221
SOUTH   567234  321456
>>total 567234  321456
CENTER  456123  987654
>>Total 456123  987654
>>>>Totals  1912245 1865331
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-repeat uses a $index value for each iteration, you could make use of this in your comparison:

`{{ uniqueitem.Region !== item[$index - 1].Region }}`

Comment: The first Region is always hidden! based on the know indices they belong i try this but did not work  : `ng-if="uniqueitem.Region === item[$index-1].Region || [0,4,13,19].indexOf($index-1) === item[$index-1].Region"` How can i display these regions ?

Comment: Could you update the example code, with what you have now? Then I can check.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

in ng-init

```
ng-init="newRegion = previousRegion!=uniqueitem.Region ;previousRegion= uniqueitem.Region"
```

in total field

```
 ng-show="newRegion"
```

Comment: Thank you anik your solution helps me to understand this kind of problem.